# Is it possible to make a class a child of two distinct hierarchies?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I would like to do the following:

```
class MyA : public ExternalA {
// some code
}

class MyB : public ExternalB {
// the same code as above
}
```

i.e. I want to extend both ExternalA and ExternalB the same way. But (for reasons) I **do not** want to do:

```
class MyC : public ExternalA, public ExternalB
{
// same code
}
```

PS, Edit: My question is about how I could avoid duplicating the code sections in the definitions of MyA and MyB.

Comment: You can do the first thing you mention by copying an pasting code. Which is a bad idea. What do you want to add in the extension? That influences the possible things to do. Are you adding data members? Functions?

Comment: @doctorlove. I need to add some attributes and methods, including overwriting methods in both ExternalA and ExternalB. If I just duplicated the code, everything would work as intended. But that is exactly what I would like to avoid. In my case, I strongly suspect ExternalA and External B to inherit from at least one common base class. But honestly I have not dug through this third party code, nor do I really want to, nor should it matter for what I want to do.

Comment: How about moving the common code out into a separate function/functions, or into a separate class?  Then the only thing that needs to be duplicated is the calls into the new helper-API; the implementation need not be duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

template might help:

```
template <typename Base>
class MyDerived : public Base
{
    // some code
};

using MyA = MyDerived<ExternalA>;
using MyB = MyDerived<ExternalB>;
```